# Enter on cypress after type is not input the value

Tags: dom, cypress

I just did a cypress curse on Udemy and I am trying to learn a bit more.
I am using this simple code line to get a box and enter a value inside using type and enter, however I am getting no error and the value is not showing inside the box.
here is the code line  `cy.get('[class="multiselect__tags"]').eq('10').type('2,000,000{enter}')`
how I am new I am using index to get the box since in the page there is more than 18 boxes with the attributes.

```
cy.get('[class="multiselect__tags"]').eq('10').type('2,000,000{enter}')
    cy.get('[class="multiselect__tags"]').eq('11').type('2,000,000{enter}')
    cy.get('[class="multiselect__tags"]').eq('12').type('1,500{enter}')
```

Here is the DOM [image]

here is how it shows in the test
[image]

[image]

[image: it is the same for the other 2 boxes as well]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) control allows the user to select items from a list, or type a value and press enter to select it.

The result is a "tag" for each of the selected items is added to the input box.

To select by typing, this is how it can be done on the demo page

```js
it('selects from vue-multiselect by typing', () => {

  cy.viewport(1000,1000)
  cy.visit('https://vue-multiselect.js.org/')

  cy.get('div.multiselect').eq(0)       // there is no id to work with so just get 1st
    .type('NO Dependencies{enter}');    // select an item

  cy.get('div.multiselect').eq(0)     // same parent as above 
    .within(() => {                   // now work within that select

      cy.get('span.multiselect__tag')          // check the tags
        .should('have.length', 1)              // only one selected
        .invoke('text')              
        .should('contain', 'NO Dependencies')  // has the expected text
    })

  cy.get('div.multiselect').eq(0)       // same select
    .type('GitHub Stars{enter}');       // select another item

  cy.get('div.multiselect').eq(0)
    .within(() => {
      cy.get('span.multiselect__tag')          // check the tags
        .should('have.length', 2)              // now two selected
        .invoke('text')              
        .should('contain', 'GitHub Stars')  // has the expected text
    })
})
```

To select by clicking the dropdown list

```
it('selects from vue-multiselect by clicking', () => {

  cy.viewport(1000,1000)
  cy.visit('https://vue-multiselect.js.org/')

  cy.get('div.multiselect').eq(0)
    .within(() => {
      cy.get('div.multiselect__select').click()  // open the dropdown
      cy.get('li.multiselect__element')
        .contains('NO Dependencies')
        .click()                                 // select an item
    })

  cy.get('div.multiselect').eq(0)     // same parent as above
    .within(() => {                   // now work within that select

      cy.get('span.multiselect__tag')          // check the tags
        .should('have.length', 1)              // only one selected
        .invoke('text')              
        .should('contain', 'NO Dependencies')  // has the expected text
    })
})
```

---

In your web page, the multiselect has a `data-vv-name` attribute which should pinpoint the particular control we want,

```js
const controlSelector = 'div.multiselect[data-vv-name="data.eoConditions.liability"]';

cy.get(controlSelector)      
  .type('2,000,000{enter}');    // select an item

cy.get(controlSelector)         // same parent as above
  .within(() => {               // work within that control

    cy.get('span.multiselect__tag')          // check the tags
      .should('have.length', 1)              // only one selected
      .invoke('text')              
      .should('contain', '2,000,000')        // has the expected text
    })

})
```

I'm not sure if you can select two values on this particular control, it does not make sense to do so since there could be only one liability limit.

Comment: thank you for answering, unfortunately it does not work. 
I am getting a error cy.type() can only be called on a single element, and my has 4. (it is reconaging the the currency dropdown) I will add a better DOM.

Comment: would it be possible to use more than 1 attribute, maybe it could work? I am trying but still with no success.

Comment: is possible to use '<ul + <list'??

Comment: your first example `cy.get('[name*="liability"]')` selected the currency dropbox and there has 4 elements (I dont need to change it). the second example `cy.get('[name$="liability]"]')'`does run the test but just says that there  _2 matches, the matched elements are no visible._ Thank you for the page I will read to learn about for the future.
do you think it would be possible open the dropdown and then choose the value? I add an image of the dropdown

Comment: It should be possible to open the dropdown and choose the limit (I did not realize it was a dropdown control). I will take a look at how this might be done. If the user can type the amount, you would ideally want to have a test for each way of selecting (clicking dropdown AND typing a value).

Comment: you are right, I should test both ways and I have no idea how. I am still search on google, github etc.